# Case Insensitive Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, spring-batch, case-insensitive

**Jaxb2Marshaller** ([org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html)) is part of Spring's O/X Mapping integration classes.

I use it as the unmarshaller of a `StaxEventItemReader` :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="marshaller">
        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
            <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                    <value>xx.xx.xx.MyBean1</value>
                    <value>xx.xx.xx.MyBean2</value>
                    <value>xx.xx.xx.MyBean3</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`MyBeanX` classes are annoted with `javax.xml.bind.annotation` annotations :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="MyBean1")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"MyBean2", "MyBean2"})
public class MyBean1 implements Serializable {

    private MyBean2 myBean2;
    private MyBean3 myBean3;

    @XmlElement(name="MyBean2")
    public MyBean2 getMyBean2() {
        return myBean2;
    }

    [...]
}
```

Unfortunately, the XMLs I need to unmarshall can have the case difference between them :

```
<MYBEAN1>
    <MYBEAN2></MYBEAN2>
    <MYBEAN3></MYBEAN3>
</MYBEAN1>    

<MyBean1>
    <MyBean2></MyBean2>
    <MyBean3></MyBean3>
</MyBean1>

<mybean1>
    <mybean2></mybean2>
    <mybean3></mybean3>
</mybean1>
```

or more variants...

Now, I need to be able to parse those XML case-insentively. What I saw so far was possible is to create a `StreamReaderDelegate` and pass the `XMLStreamReader` through it to either convert tags to lowercase or uppercase.

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file.xml"));
xsr = new MyStreamReaderDelegate(xsr);
```

Where `MyStreamReaderDelegate` looks like this :

```
private static class MyStreamReaderDelegate extends StreamReaderDelegate {

    public MyStreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
        super(xsr);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeLocalName(int index) {
        return super.getAttributeLocalName(index).toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String getLocalName() {
        return super.getLocalName().toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

My problem is I don't know what method to override (and in which class) to pass my XML through this delegate. Looking at `Jax2Marshaller` source code, I found out that an `XMLStreamReader` is used in the method `unmarshalStaxSource(Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller, Source staxSource)` :

```
private Object unmarshalStaxSource(Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller, Source staxSource) throws JAXBException {
    XMLStreamReader streamReader = StaxUtils.getXMLStreamReader(staxSource);
    if (streamReader != null) {
        return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader);
    }
    else {
        XMLEventReader eventReader = StaxUtils.getXMLEventReader(staxSource);
        if (eventReader != null) {
            return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(eventReader);
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("StaxSource contains neither XMLStreamReader nor XMLEventReader");
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, how do I override this method to add the delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use version 2.6+ of Moxy to achieve case insensitive marshalling. Heres a [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331241) to the specific enhancement that was made for the specific purpose.

You will have to set `UNMARSHALLING_CASE_INSENSITIVE` property to true. Heres some sample code

```
final StaxEventItemReader<ProductDTO> itemReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
final Jaxb2Marshaller unMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
final Map<String, Boolean> properties = Maps.newHashMap();
properties.put(UnmarshallerProperties.UNMARSHALLING_CASE_INSENSITIVE, Boolean.TRUE);
unMarshaller.setUnmarshallerProperties(properties);
itemReader.setUnmarshaller(unMarshaller);
```

Comment: This solution works only for eclipselink. Is there a common way doing this? Which for example works also for apache-wink?